# How to sound more manly when sneaking popcorn into the cinema

Tags: nuances, colloquial-language, gender

OK, really esoteric question time:

So I went to the cinema with a female friend on the weekend. 
I was going to buy some of the horrendously overpriced popcorn there, but then she said:

> 持ってきちゃった!

And she had already brought some in her bag. Apparently, ~ちゃった is quite girly though. How could I say this in a more male (but still funny) way?

Comment: How about 持ってきちゃったよ！ (in Tokyo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lol... How about [持]{も}って[来]{き}ちまったぜ！ It should sound more manly at least. BTW I'm in Kansai and I think guys here would say more like [持]{も}って[来]{き}てもうた(わ)! Doesn't it sound sooo funny?

Comment: if you want funny, you could go 持って来ちゃってもうた

Comment: @oldergod san, ん・・・？Kanto-ben plus Kansai-ben??

Comment: You wanted funny ;) Works fine for me !

Answer (score 4):

～ちゃった is not funny and is not girly.

The difference is mainly how you say it. It can also depends on where you live.

Answer (score 2):

~ちゃった is not particularly "funny", just female-tinged and rather casual. Note that men can occasionally use it...

The rest sounds more like a standard (and many time answered) [male vs female speech question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-differences-should-i-look-out-for-between-male-vs-female-pronunciation).

(note: taking a page from my own book and posting this as an answer instead of a comment)

Comment: I don't see ~ちゃった as particularly female-tinged, at least in standard Japanese. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @dainichi: as I pointed out, I don't see it as exclusively female (certainly use it myself on occasions). But its use is skewed toward "feminine" speech... Such discussions are highly subjective (see the link in my answer), but I think most Japanese would tell you the overuse of '〜ちゃった' forms sounds rather infantile/feminine (possibly feminine *because* infantile... welcome to Japan). Also: I'm not sure what you mean by 'standard Japanese', but this form is definitely not 標準語...

Comment: It is 標準語 for me. What is 標準語 for you Dave? Isn't it 関東弁?

Comment: @oldergod: I have no idea what you are trying to say :-)

Comment: @Dave Some Kansai-ben speakers think Tokyo-ben sounds effeminate, just as some Tokyo-ben people think Kansai-Ben sounds rough. Your *perception* might be subjective, but in Tokyo, ちゃった is equally used by males and females, and that's a *fact*. Whether ちゃった can be considered 標準語 or not is a different question which I won't comment on.

Comment: @dainichi: I've lived in both Kanto and Kansai and probably spoke more Tokyo-ben before I even heard any serious Kansai-ben. It might  be "my perception" (doubt it is, seeing as I have had enough drawn out discussions with natives of how feminine such or such forms might be), but I fail to see your "fact" (source, please?). 標準語 has a pretty specific and strict definition. Without digging too deep, I am pretty sure I have never heard an NHK announcer use "〜ちゃった" other than in set-expressions.

Comment: @oldergod: in light of dainichi's comment, I *think* I understand what you were trying to say (please correct me if I'm wrong) and in that case, you might be a little confused about the standard meaning of [標準語](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/標準語). It is not a subjective concept :-) and neither tokyo-ben or kansai-ben, regardless of speaker (kinda the point).

Comment: Really ? *現在の日本には標準語を定義する機関が存在しないため、法的には標準語は存在しないと言える。しかしながら日常会話において「標準語」という用語は現在もしばしば使用され、その場合「標準語」は東京の口語（東京方言や首都圏方言）を指すことが多い。* The whole article only relate it to what is spoken in Tokyo.

Comment: I really do not think Hyojungo is the same as Tokyo-ben (not to mention, Kansai-ben), but frankly, if that's not somewhat obvious to you, I don't have the time to dig out better references, and this is not the place to have that debate anyway.

Comment: *Frankly*, I just read the reference *you* gave me.

Comment: @Dave I don't think whether you're heard an NHK announcer use it or not proves anything. I've never heard one use `お前` either, but I still consider that 標準語.