# Questions with 辞書形　and raising tone and 辞書形＋の？

Tags: usage, particle-の, questions, spoken-language

I was tonight with japanese friends and I noticed they rather used a simple 辞書形　form along with a raising tone to ask a question, although we learned in class that "non-polite" questions were formed with 辞書形+の. Is there a difference between the two ? From this topic "[Is ending question sentences with の really feminine?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11914/is-ending-question-sentences-with-%E3%81%AE-really-feminine)" I gathered that の might have a feminine touch when used along with statements, but what about questions in general ? Can I use の without sounding like a weirdo ? I also heard the two, along with no-verb questions in an anime I'm currently watching, Ergo Proxy, but I guess these are used whenever the verb and/or subject are well defined by the context... To summarize with examples :

- どこへ行くの？
- どこへ行く？
- どこへ？

What's the difference between the above examples ? Can I use any of those in any given situation ?
Thanks, ウルカン

Comment: So your main question is "what's the difference"?

Comment: Yes what's the difference. And I hope the answer would include some hint as to when or in which situation to use which !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use の without sounding like a weirdo ?

Yes.

> Is there a difference between the two ?

Yes. A question with の is usually asking about a reason, or following up on a piece of information. For example, 勉強しているの？ means "are you studying?", and might have undertones of "is *that* why (e.g.) you can't come out tonight?", whereas 勉強している？ is a straightforward yes/no question. Compare 勉強している ("I am studying") with 勉強しているのだ ("(it's because) I am studying").