# What's the meaning of the ending じゃないの?

Tags: meaning, usage

I found it twice. First in a song:

> いつもその本はハッピーエンドじゃないの。

And then the title of a manga:

> 遊びじゃないの。

じゃない alone is for negation (no happy end, no playing).
What I can't understand is the の at the end of the sentence... what does it stand for?

Comment: じゃない, believe it or not, is for AFFIRMATION half the time.  It all depends on the context.

Comment: And that makes things more complicated... any example, please?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/453/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%9F%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-expression-in-spoken-japanese/505#505

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%82%93-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: @Alox Thanks, the use of じゃない is clearer now. Still my doubt about の remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Is ending question sentences with の really feminine?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11914/is-ending-question-sentences-with-%E3%81%AE-really-feminine)

の(だ)/のです with a rising tone are the abbreviations of の(だ)か/のですか。

**(The combination だか isn't really used in everyday life to the best of my knowledge)**.

They turn the sentence into a question which, combined with じゃない make it a tag question, as you can see in the links I posted in my comments.

> 遊びじゃない？
> 遊びじゃないか。
> 遊びじゃないの（か）？
>
> It's a game isn't it? It's a game right? You're playing aren't you?

Without the rising tone (or か), じゃない is used to deny what precedes it. の/のだ/のです　have many different meanings (look it up on this site), the most common ones being adding an explanatory and/or exclamative tone to the sentence.

> 遊びじゃないの（だ）。遊びじゃないのです。
>
> It's not a game. It' not a game! (What the hell are you doing, ) it's not a game! (I can't believe you take it so lightly, ) it's not a game (you know?).

The sentences in の are often used to answer the implicit question "What is happening?" : "Well, what's happening is..."

> 誰かが来た？ (Gathering information after coming home).
>
> Someone came?
>
> 誰かが来たの？ (Seeing 2 cups of coffee on the table).
>
> (What happened,) someone came?

I don't feel comfortable enough with those grammar to go further into details, I would advise you to look for informations about the differences between だ/です VS の（だ）/のです and （だ）か/ですか VS の(だ)か/のですか.

---

EDIT : Just to be clear, here are the different forms :

Simple　　　　　　　　　Abbreviated　　　　　　　　　Using の　　　　　　　　　Abbreviated using の

猫だ。 　　　　　　　　　猫。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　猫なのだ。　　　　　　　　　猫なの。

猫です。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　猫なのです。

猫（**だ**）か。 　　　　　　猫だ？/猫？　　　　　　　　　猫なの（**だ**）か。　　　　　　猫なのだ？/猫なの？

猫ですか。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　猫なのですか。　　　　　　猫なのです？

Comment: Just to see if I got it right (there are too many cases!)
いつもその本はハッピーエンドじゃないの。 could be translated in something like: 'those books always have a happy ending, haven't they?' or 'those books always have a happy ending, you know?'. Is it correct?

Comment: I think so yeah, or "His/her books always..." if you were talking about an author I guess.

Comment: だか is used, but only in subordinate clauses.