# What is the meaning of たい形＋の＋名詞: 「逃げ出したいのジュリエット。」

Tags: grammar, particle-の, song-lyrics

This is a part of the song "ロミオとシンデレラ"

> 逃げ出したい**の**ジュリエット。
> でもその名前で呼ばないで。
> そうよね 結ばれなくちゃね。
> そうじゃないと楽しくないわ。
> ねえ 私と生きてくれる？

I would like to know the grammatical function of that "no" and how it differs from a simple "逃げ出したいジュリエット" without the "no". I believe that's just a more poetical way of saying the same thing, but I'm not sure. Perhaps a more informal way of saying???

Answer (score 3):

I'd interpret it as:

> 逃げ出したいの、ジュリエット(は)。
> ≈ ジュリエット(は)、逃げ出したいの。

"I want to run away." said by Juliet herself.

The の is a feminine sentence ending の.

Here's a related thread:

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11915/9831

> Decidedly feminine is when you end a statement in の, e.g.
>
> そうなのよ。
> 知らなかったの。
>
> with the male equivalent being either nothing (e.g. そう, 知らなかった) or んだ(よ) (e.g. そうなんだよ, 知らなかったんだよ).