# What does みてえじゃ in this sentence mean?

Tags: slang

What does みてえじゃ in this sentence mean ?

> 困ってるみてえじゃねえか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just another example of the `ai`-to-`ee` sound change found mainly in dialectal or male speech, which is described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/99/5010) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13073/5010).

困ってるみてえじゃねえか is the same as 困ってるみたいじゃないか.

In case you don't know みたい, see [this](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=mitai).

Answer (score 4):

みてえじゃねえか is an unrefined expression of みたいじゃないか. It is frequently used in an ironic sense, so be careful to read the context.

Comment: By 'rude' I guess you mean in the sense of 'unrefined'; it may be understood the wrong way.

Comment: @oals Thank you for your comment. I will correct the part.