# すき ("suki") vs すきだ ("sukida")

Tags: grammar

#### Background

I am currently studying Japanese grammar at a beginner's level. Yes, I am familiar with Hiragana but I have not quite learnt Katakana yet. Obviously, I know Romaji and hardly much Kanji.

#### Problem

However, I came across the formal and informal way of using "suki" (すき). I know "desu" is required if you were to say to your boss "I like apples" but is "da" really necessary for informal? I mean, is it as polite if you went without it? Is it grammatically correct or right to go without it?

For example, what's the difference between りんごが好き ("I like apples") and and with だ on the end (sentence + grammatical particle perhaps?)

Comment: "りんごが好"... did you mean "りんごが好き"?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think that sukida is more casual, whereas suki have a sense of lightheartedness to it. Just my personal opinion:P

Comment: Aw, thank you. So, I would use sukida with friends, right? Maybe suki with family, even if they are not Japanese. <3 XD

Answer (score 9):

Including sentence-final だ is a marker of **blunt-style** speech, typical of males. The alternate without だ is more apt to be used in feminine/gentle speech.

For more detail on this particular nuance, see this question:

[Is "da" used often in the casual speech?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35893/is-da-used-often-in-the-casual-speech/35895)

And for information about other patterns typical of blunt/gentle speech styles, see this question:

[What differences should I look out for between male vs female speech?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-differences-should-i-look-out-for-between-male-vs-female-speech)

Comment: My masculine side and my feminine side. Thank you for the response! So, it's less polite and more informal, right?

Comment: Casual speech is not polite in any case (though that doesn't preclude it from having 敬語, which can add humble/honorific/neutral politeness to speech). Neither 好き nor 好きだ is "polite," and neither is more polite than the other; though 好き, compared to 好きだ , is less abrasive/blunt. If you want to be polite, use distal style, e.g. 好きです.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 好き{すき} could be translated as "something that someone likes" (it means "to like" but it's an adjective). So if you want to say "I like apples" you must say りんごが好{す}きです. だ is the informal version of です. If you are with your friends, you should say りんごが好き{すき}だ. But sometimes people (particularly women) skip だ when talking in colloquial speech. So you could leave it in りんごが好き{すき}.

To summarise, 好き{すき} is an adjective, that may be alone (informal, femenine), with だ (informal in general) or with です (formal).